# (Vue3) Problems syncing DOM element heights change using v-model and v-on

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3, v-model

I am creating a website in which the value of a range slider is bound using `v-model`, to a property called `rangeValue`. The code looks similar to the following:

```
    <template>
       ...
      <input
        type="range"
        min="10"
        max="50"
        class="slider"
        v-model="rangeValue"
        @change="updateHeight()"
      />
      <div class="otherDiv" :style="{ height: `${wrapperHeight}px`></>
      <div
        class="firstDiv"
        ref="first"
        :style="{ width: `${rangeValue}rem` }">
           <!-- There are elements inside whose height is also bound by rangeValue, and some that are toggled on/off via other checkbox inputs, thereby changing the height of firstDiv -->
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          wrapperHeight: 0,
          rangeValue: "10",
      },
      mounted(){
          this.wrapperHeight = this.$refs.first.offsetHeight;
      },
      methods: {
        updateHeight() {
          this.wrapperHeight = this.$refs.first.offsetHeight;
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    <style>
      ...
    </style>
```

I would like to make the height of `otherDiv` match the height of `firstDiv`, whose height changes based on range slider changes. My problem is that the height of `firstDiv` updates concurrently with the range slider changes, while the height of `otherDiv` always lags one "tick" behind, updating to the value of the `firstDiv` before it's been changed by the range slider, rather than after. I have tried all sorts of implementations using `nextTick` to no avail.

In short, I would need to:

1. Update range slider
2. Resize `firstDiv`, get its height in the DOM, resize `otherDiv`
3. Repaint DOM (so both are resized at the same time).

I hope this makes sense. Any pointers are more than welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
const { createApp, toRefs, reactive, computed } = Vue

createApp({
  setup: () =>
    toRefs(
      reactive({
        h8: 135
      })
    )
}).mount("#app")
```

```css
#app .grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.75rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  
}
#app .grid > * {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0/10%),
    inset 0 3px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 7%),
    inset 0 3px 3px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
#app [type="range"] {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="range" min="60" max="400" v-model="h8" />
  <div class="grid" :style="{ height: `${h8}px` }">
    <div class="firstDiv">first div</div>
    <div class="secondDiv">
      second div
      <p v-for="n in 10" :key="n">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You're not limited to having a common parent (it just seemed more appropriate for your case).

You can have completely unrelated components synced, even in separate apps (see below example). All you need is a single source of truth. I used a reactive object but a more common and useful implementation is to use an actual store (pinia, vuex):

```js
const { createApp, toRefs, reactive, computed } = Vue

const store = reactive({
  h8: 85
});
['input-app', 'app-1', 'app-2'].forEach(app => createApp({
  setup: () => toRefs(store)
}).mount(`#${app}`))
```

```css
#app-1, #app-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "input input"
    "app-1 app-2";
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body { margin: 0 }
#input-app {
  grid-area: input;
}
#app-1 {
  grid-area: app-1;
}
#app-2 {
  grid-area: app-2;
  align-self: end;
}
.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0/10%),
    inset 0 3px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 7%),
    inset 0 3px 3px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
[type="range"] {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="input-app">
    <input type="range" min="60" max="500" v-model="h8" />
  </div>
  <div id="app-1">
    <div class="firstDiv" :style="{ height: `${h8}px` }">
      first div
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="app-2">
    <div class="secondDiv" :style="{ height: `${h8}px` }">
      second div
      <p v-for="n in 10" :key="n">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Essentially, I am looking to have one component's width synced to a reactive property, set via the slider as in your example. When the slider changes, however, I am also looking to update another div's height according to the computed height of the first div. At the moment, my problem is the one tick lag that happens when I try to implement this functionality... It seems like the @change event listener reads the DOM OffsetHeight the value before the data property has been updated, rather than concurrently or right after. I hope it makes sense!

Comment: @DmnkVD, could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? And explain in clear what you're trying to avoid? Use codesandbox (or similar) if you need a node-like environment. I can't be sure until you give me something to inspect, but you might want to replace `@change` with `@input` or with a `watch` on `rangeValue`.

Comment: Point being: you should only be updating state (which you already are, by using `v-model`, so `@change` is useless there - you can get the change from the `v-model` prop). And you should be using the same source for all your DOM updates. Another question for you is: 1 tick is not a perceptible difference, even when it is there. What makes you believe that could be an issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I have tried to implement watch, to no avail. Here is a link to a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-forest-cco3l1?file=/src/App.vue, which shows the problem of the left column "lagging behind".  I need this type of layout in my use-case where I need to match the height of a fixed left-side column with the dynamically resizable contents of a table on the right.

Comment: Move `otherBox` inside `boxOneContainer`, make `boxOneContainer` `position: relative` and `otherBox` `height: 100%`. [Done](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-brattain-2rljtp?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: Or if, for any reason, you don't want to have `otherBox` inside `boxOneContainer`, create a new element around `otherBox` and `boxOneContainer`. Give it `position: relative`. And then give `otherBox`: `height: 100%`. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dream-lfp7el?file=/src/App.vue). 
And ultimately, if, for any reason, you don't want to make any mods to markup, you could just wrap the watcher execution into `nextTick()`, available from `vue`. See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-tess-tcqyct?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: Out of principle, as much as possible, you should only create layouts which naturally update after user input, so you don't need to wait for layout to get rendered and then update it again. In other words, any state changes should see their layout effect in one tick, never in two. This principle becomes ever more important the bigger the codebase, the bigger the company and the more dev hands the code needs to change, from a dev to another. Your code is 1 iteration away from becoming a *"I'm not touching it, it works!"* type of code. And you don't want to be that guy.

Comment: For example, BootstrapVue broke this principle in a few places, one of them being their dropdowns. Resulting in tests needing sometimes 3-4 nested `$nextTick`s to pass. This resulted in poor UX and even poorer developer experience (DX). People simply gave up unit-testing anything that would involve dropdown components. Or using stand alone dropdown plugins instead of the provided dropdown component. Which is pretty bad for a component library.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful pointers. I have updated my [codesandbox](codesandbox.io/s/still-forest-cco3l1?file=/src/App.vue) to better reflect the product I am building, which hopefully explains why I need the type of layout I have devised and cannot change the div structure with `position: relative` as you suggested. With the API data, I have around 100 rows over 30 columns. On my development machine, the NextTick solution sadly does not seem to work, the one-frame lag remains... I am unsure if my solution can work at all at this point.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful pointers. I have updated my example (codesandbox.io/s/still-forest-cco3l1?file=/src/App.vue) to better reflect the product I am building, which hopefully explains why I need the type of layout I have devised and cannot change the div structure with `position: relative` as you suggested. With the API data, I have around 100 rows over 30 columns. On my development machine, the NextTick solution sadly does not seem to work, the one-frame lag remains... I am unsure if my solution can work at all at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251132/discussion-between-tao-and-dmnkvd).

Answer (score -1):

I don't really get your goal and height/width relation.

But here is a working playground with something alike.

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {    
    const mydiv = ref(null);     
    const wrapperHeight = ref(0);        
    const rangeValue = ref(50);        
    
    onMounted(() => { 
      console.log(`onMounted(): ${mydiv.value.offsetHeight}`);
      wrapperHeight.value = mydiv.value.offsetHeight;
    });        
    
    const updateHeight = (event) => { 
      console.log(`updateHeight(): ${event.target.value}`);
      wrapperHeight.value = event.target.value;
    }
    
    return {mydiv, wrapperHeight, rangeValue, updateHeight }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"> 
   <input
        type="range"
        min="10"
        max="100"
        class="slider"
        v-model="rangeValue"
        @change="updateHeight"
      /><br/>
   rangeValue: {{rangeValue}} <br/>
   wrapperHeight: {{wrapperHeight}} <br/><br/>
   <div :style="{ 'background-color': 'yellow', 'min-height': `${wrapperHeight}px` }">
      <div ref="mydiv" style="{ 'float': 'bottom' }">My Div</div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My problem is that I have div `firstDiv` height linked to the slider, and `otherDiv`'s height link to `firstDiv`'s height that I get using the ref's height in the DOM. When I change the slider, firstDiv changes accordingly, and otherDiv lags one step behind. It only changes to firstDiv's value before the beginning of slider input.